# Two-factor authentication via mobile phone on Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vpn, authentication

Is it possible to set up two factor VPN authentication on Windows Server 2008 R2?

In other words: when someone tries to connect to a corporate VPN, they are sent an SMS with a code, which they then need to also enter along with their usual username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Specific product recommendations are off topic here, but in a general sense, "phonefactor" solutions (AKA 2-factor authentication that involves your mobile phone) are usually simple RADIUS proxies that work in conjunction with the Windows Server RRAS (Routing and Remote Access Role) and are pretty easy to set up.